# Time-varying data: list of tuples vs 2D array?

Tags: python, scientific-computing

My example code is in python but I'm asking about the general principle.

If I have a set of data in time-value pairs, should I store these as a 2D array or as a list of tuples? for instance, if I have this data:

```
v=[1,4,4,4,23,4]
t=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Is it generally better to store it like this:

```
data=[v,t]
```

or as a list of tuples:

```
data=[(1,1),(4,2)(4,3)...]
```

Is there a "standard" way of doing this?

Comment: It all depends on how you intend to use the data.

Comment: This is one of those situations where I don't know how I may use the data in the future, although doing things like plots and statistical analysis on the data is likely, this is why I decided that JoshAdel's solution is probably the one most suited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregate array container is probably the best choice. Assuming that your time points are not regularly spaced (and therefore you need to keep track of it rather than just use the indexing), this allows you to take slices of your entire data set like:

```
import numpy as np
v=[1,4,4,4,23,4]
t=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

data = np.array([v,t])
```

Then you could slice it to get a subset of the data easily:

```
data[:,2:4]  #array([[4, 4],[3, 4]])

ii = [1,2,5] # Fancy indexing
data[:,ii] # array([[4, 4, 4],
           #        [2, 3, 6]])
```

Comment: Thanks! I think on reflection this is probably the most suited because aside from making slices easy it also makes it quick and natural to do things like make plots from your data.

Comment: @Mike: Glad I could be of help. If you think this is useful, you should up-vote it and/or mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 4):

If speed is your biggest concern, in Python, look at Numpy.

In general, you should choose choose a data structure that makes dealing with the data natural and easy. Worry about speed later, after you know it works!

As for an easy data structure, how about an list of tuples:

```
v=[1,4,4,4,23,4]
t=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

data=[(1,1),(4,2)(4,3)...]
```

Then you can unpack like so:

```
v,t=data[1]
#v,t are 4,2
```

Comment: This approach is good unless you need to look up items in one collection against items in the other, when you may wish to use an associative data type such as a Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a dictionary? In other languages this may be known as a hash-map, hash-table, associative array, or some other term which means the same thing. Of course it depends on how you intend to access your data.

Instead of:

```
v=[1,4,4,4,23,4]
t=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

you'd have:

```
v_with_t_as_key = {1:1,  # excuse the name...
                   2:4, 
                   3:4, 
                   4:4, 
                   5:23, 
                   6:4}
```

This is a fairly standard construct in python, although if order is important you might want to look at the ordered [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) in [collections](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: This is not recommended if you want easy access to slices of data. This binds you to retrieving a single time point at a time, and you have to manipulate/recast your data structure to get it in ways other than single key,value pairs.

Comment: @JoshAdel: This is a valid point, although it can be solved by choosing a different implementation of this sort of data type. Essentially this sort of associative data structure makes dealing with associative data easier to grok in your code, but there may be other concers depending on your project @Mike

Answer (score 0):

I've found that for exploring and prototyping, it's more convenient to store as a list/jagged array of columns, where the first column is the observational index and each column after that is a variable.

data=[(1,2,3,4,5,6),(1,4,4,4,23,4)]

Most of the time i'm loading many observations with many variables, and then performing sorting, formatting, or displaying one or more of those variables, or even joining two sets of data with columns as parameters.  It's a lot rarer when I need to pull a subset of observations out.  Even if I did, it's more convenient to use a function that returns a subset of the data given a column of observation indexes.

Having said that, I still use functions to convert jagged arrays to 2d arrays and to transpose 2d arrays.